# get struts2 multiple checkboxlist value without checkboxlist

Tags: struts2

I create multiple checkboxes using iterator
In my case I can't use checkboxlist

```
<s:iterator value="tree" status="statusVar">
   <s:property value="openTag" escape="false"/>
   <s:if test="%{closeTag==null}">
         <s:checkbox name="%{lable}" fieldValue="%{lable}" value="%{lable}"/>
  </s:if>
  <s:property value="lable" escape="false"/>
  <s:property value="closeTag" escape="false"/>
</s:iterator>
```

How can I get selected values those checkboxes

Comment: Why do use dynamic name attribute? Do you really need it?

Comment: yes this list comes form database. I can't say how many indexes in it. can I use static name and dynamic value attribute in this situation???

Comment: Do you want to get selected values after form submit?

Comment: yes. I want to get selected checkbox values

Comment: Use `<s:checkbox name="someVar" .../>`

Comment: Can you describe `tree`? What type ist it? What fields does its type have? Is it supposed to hold the selected values or the labels?

Comment: it is support to labels. simply any body can tell can i get my form input values to arraylist or some list without declaring variable for all indexes in my support class